# How do stumble mechanics work?

Tags: killing-floor-2

I unlocked an ability in the third tier of SWAT perks. It says:

> Increases stumble power 100% with all perk weapons.

What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, stumble is caused by shooting a Zed's legs, causing them to "stumble", which slows them down. From [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GDpg2mN1l_86U_RaDug0glFx8cZCuErwxZLiBKl9SyY/htmlview?pli=1#gid=2068776317):

> Stumble is a special move where ZED goes into "stumble" stance. Hits from different angles cause different stumble animations, each stumble animation has its own duration. After playing stumble animation for random (0.5-0.75) seconds ZED will be able to interrupt it by taking hit from the weapon which Melee hit power / Gun hit power will be greater than ZED's Melee hit / Gun hit resistance. Additionally ZED should not be in cooldown to applied type of the power, otherwise stumble animation will not be interrupted.

Essentially, what this perk does is increase the chance of inflicting the Stumble effect by double.

Thus, if you have this perk enabled, shooting at the legs will have a much better chance of crippling approaching Zeds, which will cause them to briefly stop. This will allow you a chance to get some extra shots in (and hopefully kill them) or increase your distance from them before they resume their assault and reach you.